# Help understanding options hidden and nostartofline

Tags: vimrc, options

I am writing my first vimrc. I already read help pages for `hidden` and `nostartofline` options, as well as [some articles](https://www.facebook.com/vimtips/posts/405674039570379) and other FAQs.

However, I still can't understand what the purpose of these two options are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps examples will help you understand the features:

### 'hidden'

1. Start a new instance of Vim in the terminal with the command `vim -Nu NONE`. This will start Vim with default configuration, and thus `'hidden'` will be unset (and `'startofline'` will be set).
2. Enter insert mode by pressing <kbd>i</kbd>, type in some text, and then press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to return to normal mode,
3. Enter the command `:e anotherfile.txt` to start editing a new file,
4. Vim will display an error because you haven't written the file yet,
5. Enter the command `:set hidden` to switch on the `'hidden'` option
6. Try the command again: `:e anotherfile.txt`.

What happens?

### 'nostartofline'

1. In the same instance of Vim, enter the command `:b#`to return to your original buffer.
2. Press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> to jump to the beginning of the buffer and then `$` to jump to the end of the line. (If the first line is blank, first enter some text.)
3. Press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> again. The cursor will move to the start of the line.
4. Press <kbd>$</kbd> to move back to the end of the line,
5. Enter the command `:set nostartofline`.
6. Press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> a third time.

What happens?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two additional examples for `nostartofline`.

First, open a new buffer, paste/type the following code, type `:nostartofline`, and then switch to Normal mode.

```
if (x == y) {
        dosomething1
}

dosomething2
```

Then:

**Example 1**

1. Place the cursor on `x`.
2. Press VG to select the whole text.
3. Notice your cursor is now on `m` and not `d` in `dosomething2`.

**Example 2**

1. Place the cursor on `d` in `dosomething1`
2. Press >> to indent this line.
3. Notice your cursor was not moved.